# RijndaelManaged decryption using memorystream from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I want to decrypt excel file and store data into a csv file. Which methods can I use in PHP?

I have example code of decrypt file in C#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE 16 BYTE KEY!!! //
       String secretKey = "050WC6tJuL@#*%^&";
       // For this demo, we are using a local file //
       String inputFile = "Sample.xlsx.encrypted";
       // ...and saving to a local file too!  
       String outputFile = "Sample.csv";
       try
        {
            // We are using an AES Crypto with ECB and PKCS7 Padding
            using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
                byte[] IV = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);

                aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                int data;
                                while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                                {
                                    fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
                                }
                                cs.Flush();
                                cs.Close();
                                fsOut.Flush();
                                fsOut.Close();
                                fsCrypt.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // failed to decrypt file
            Console.WriteLine("Errors : "+ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I hope you don't actually use that code.  Are you aware that under the right circumstances it would be very easy to retrieve the plaintext?

Comment: I can't edit because it shows "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error message.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code conversion service. BTW, I didn't know you had to close explicitly when using `using`.